# Storing Hex Colors in a column in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, datatypes

I want to store Hex color codes in a column in my Postgres database. I would like to put a restriction on the column to ensure it has the format of being a hex color (Example: `#FFAA00`)
Some Example of the restrictions would be: It must start with a `#`. It must be 7 characters. I found the following method to accomplish this, but is there a better more simple way to do this?

```sql
ALTER TABLE stone.event_type_tags
    ADD CONSTRAINT hex_color
        CHECK (
                (
                    color IS NULL
                )
             OR (
                    (
                    LENGTH(color) = 7
                    )
                AND (
                        substr(color,1,1) = '#'
                    )
                AND (
                        (substr(color,2,1) = '0')
                     OR (substr(color,2,1) = '1')
                     OR (substr(color,2,1) = '2')
                     OR (substr(color,2,1) = '3')
                     OR (substr(color,2,1) = '4')
                     OR (substr(color,2,1) = '5')
                     OR (substr(color,2,1) = '6')
                     OR (substr(color,2,1) = '7')
                     OR (substr(color,2,1) = '8')
                     OR (substr(color,2,1) = '9')
                     OR (substr(color,2,1) = 'A')
                     OR (substr(color,2,1) = 'B')
                     OR (substr(color,2,1) = 'C')
                     OR (substr(color,2,1) = 'D')
                     OR (substr(color,2,1) = 'E')
                     OR (substr(color,2,1) = 'F')
                     OR (substr(color,2,1) = 'a')
                     OR (substr(color,2,1) = 'b')
                     OR (substr(color,2,1) = 'c')
                     OR (substr(color,2,1) = 'd')
                     OR (substr(color,2,1) = 'e')
                     OR (substr(color,2,1) = 'f')
                    )
                AND (
                        (substr(color,3,1) = '0')
                     OR (substr(color,3,1) = '1')
                     OR (substr(color,3,1) = '2')
                     OR (substr(color,3,1) = '3')
                     OR (substr(color,3,1) = '4')
                     OR (substr(color,3,1) = '5')
                     OR (substr(color,3,1) = '6')
                     OR (substr(color,3,1) = '7')
                     OR (substr(color,3,1) = '8')
                     OR (substr(color,3,1) = '9')
                     OR (substr(color,3,1) = 'A')
                     OR (substr(color,3,1) = 'B')
                     OR (substr(color,3,1) = 'C')
                     OR (substr(color,3,1) = 'D')
                     OR (substr(color,3,1) = 'E')
                     OR (substr(color,3,1) = 'F')
                     OR (substr(color,3,1) = 'a')
                     OR (substr(color,3,1) = 'b')
                     OR (substr(color,3,1) = 'c')
                     OR (substr(color,3,1) = 'd')
                     OR (substr(color,3,1) = 'e')
                     OR (substr(color,3,1) = 'f')
                    )
                AND (
                        (substr(color,4,1) = '0')
                     OR (substr(color,4,1) = '1')
                     OR (substr(color,4,1) = '2')
                     OR (substr(color,4,1) = '3')
                     OR (substr(color,4,1) = '4')
                     OR (substr(color,4,1) = '5')
                     OR (substr(color,4,1) = '6')
                     OR (substr(color,4,1) = '7')
                     OR (substr(color,4,1) = '8')
                     OR (substr(color,4,1) = '9')
                     OR (substr(color,4,1) = 'A')
                     OR (substr(color,4,1) = 'B')
                     OR (substr(color,4,1) = 'C')
                     OR (substr(color,4,1) = 'D')
                     OR (substr(color,4,1) = 'E')
                     OR (substr(color,4,1) = 'F')
                     OR (substr(color,4,1) = 'a')
                     OR (substr(color,4,1) = 'b')
                     OR (substr(color,4,1) = 'c')
                     OR (substr(color,4,1) = 'd')
                     OR (substr(color,4,1) = 'e')
                     OR (substr(color,4,1) = 'f')
                    )
                AND (
                        (substr(color,5,1) = '0')
                     OR (substr(color,5,1) = '1')
                     OR (substr(color,5,1) = '2')
                     OR (substr(color,5,1) = '3')
                     OR (substr(color,5,1) = '4')
                     OR (substr(color,5,1) = '5')
                     OR (substr(color,5,1) = '6')
                     OR (substr(color,5,1) = '7')
                     OR (substr(color,5,1) = '8')
                     OR (substr(color,5,1) = '9')
                     OR (substr(color,5,1) = 'A')
                     OR (substr(color,5,1) = 'B')
                     OR (substr(color,5,1) = 'C')
                     OR (substr(color,5,1) = 'D')
                     OR (substr(color,5,1) = 'E')
                     OR (substr(color,5,1) = 'F')
                     OR (substr(color,5,1) = 'a')
                     OR (substr(color,5,1) = 'b')
                     OR (substr(color,5,1) = 'c')
                     OR (substr(color,5,1) = 'd')
                     OR (substr(color,5,1) = 'e')
                     OR (substr(color,5,1) = 'f')
                    )
                AND (
                        (substr(color,6,1) = '0')
                     OR (substr(color,6,1) = '1')
                     OR (substr(color,6,1) = '2')
                     OR (substr(color,6,1) = '3')
                     OR (substr(color,6,1) = '4')
                     OR (substr(color,6,1) = '5')
                     OR (substr(color,6,1) = '6')
                     OR (substr(color,6,1) = '7')
                     OR (substr(color,6,1) = '8')
                     OR (substr(color,6,1) = '9')
                     OR (substr(color,6,1) = 'A')
                     OR (substr(color,6,1) = 'B')
                     OR (substr(color,6,1) = 'C')
                     OR (substr(color,6,1) = 'D')
                     OR (substr(color,6,1) = 'E')
                     OR (substr(color,6,1) = 'F')
                     OR (substr(color,6,1) = 'a')
                     OR (substr(color,6,1) = 'b')
                     OR (substr(color,6,1) = 'c')
                     OR (substr(color,6,1) = 'd')
                     OR (substr(color,6,1) = 'e')
                     OR (substr(color,6,1) = 'f')
                    )
                AND (
                        (substr(color,7,1) = '0')
                     OR (substr(color,7,1) = '1')
                     OR (substr(color,7,1) = '2')
                     OR (substr(color,7,1) = '3')
                     OR (substr(color,7,1) = '4')
                     OR (substr(color,7,1) = '5')
                     OR (substr(color,7,1) = '6')
                     OR (substr(color,7,1) = '7')
                     OR (substr(color,7,1) = '8')
                     OR (substr(color,7,1) = '9')
                     OR (substr(color,7,1) = 'A')
                     OR (substr(color,7,1) = 'B')
                     OR (substr(color,7,1) = 'C')
                     OR (substr(color,7,1) = 'D')
                     OR (substr(color,7,1) = 'E')
                     OR (substr(color,7,1) = 'F')
                     OR (substr(color,7,1) = 'a')
                     OR (substr(color,7,1) = 'b')
                     OR (substr(color,7,1) = 'c')
                     OR (substr(color,7,1) = 'd')
                     OR (substr(color,7,1) = 'e')
                     OR (substr(color,7,1) = 'f')
                    )
                 )
              );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [regular expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) for that:

```
check (color is null or color ~* '^#[a-f0-9]{2}[a-f0-9]{2}[a-f0-9]{2}$')
```

Comment: Why not '^#[a-f0-9]{6}$' ?

Comment: Now that I understand this more I think I can comment. I think he wants to do it that way to separate out each color

Answer (score 1):

Let me share what I did in my tests:

1. Create table

```
CREATE TABLE colors (id integer primary key, color VARCHAR(7) null);
```

2. Add constraint

```
ALTER TABLE colors
ADD CONSTRAINT color_hex_constraint
CHECK (color is null or color ~* '^#[a-f0-9]{6}$');
```

3. Test

```
insert into colors values (1, '#ff00ff'); -- OK
insert into colors values (2, null);      -- OK
insert into colors values (3, '');        -- ERROR
insert into colors values (4, 'pg');      -- ERROR

select * from colors;
```

4. Drop

```
ALTER TABLE colors DROP CONSTRAINT color_hex_constraint; -- only constraint
DROP TABLE colors; -- all
```

---

See also: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-createtype.html